# cgroups in CentOS

Tags: cpu, centos, linux-kvm

I am using a KVM to manage my VMs.

I would like to limit the CPU usage of a particular VM (set a cap on the VM). I was using xen all along, and was able to do this using credit scheduler. I am new to KVM and am searching for some tools to do the same thing.

I found that cgroups can do it but I'm not sure how to install and use cgroups in CentOS. I did some searching but couldn't find any how tos for CentOS.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This may seem very obvious, but also search for Red Hat and Fedora docs. CentOS is a clone of Red Hat.

Comment: Cgroups apparently are available in RHEL / CentOS 6.x only, you didn't specify your version. But the information available is sketchy at best, I was unable to find a reasonable howto.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL's and Fedora's Resource Management Guide is a good place to look for decent documentation on cgroups.

Do you have any specific questions about cgroups?